# Suppose to write an exponent in python, can't figure out what i'm dong wrong

Tags: python

I'm supposed to calculate X to the Y and output the final result.

```
 for i in range (X):
   X, Y = Y, X
 print (X)
```

this is what i get

Program Failed for Input: 1 2
Expected Output: 1
Your Program Output: 2

What's wrong with the program?

Comment: Why are you using a `for` loop?  What is `X`?  You're not giving us much to work with here.

Comment: X is a system variable, i'm using a for loop because it seemed like the easiest way to do it at the time, though i think i might have been wrong about that

Comment: Okay, I was reading the question of your text wrong.  Treyton seems to have the correct answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you are currently doing:

```
for i in range (X):
  # for the first input number (1), swap X and Y
  X, Y = Y, X

# because X is 1 and Y is 2, and you swapped them once, X is now 2 and Y is 1
print (X)
```

Here is what you should do:

```
Ans = 1 # store the new answer
for i in range(Y):
  Ans = Ans*X # multiply the answer by X (doing this Y times)

# print the answer
print(Ans)
```

Comment: Though this will produce the right value for 1^2, because you're modifying X, it won't be correct for most cases. For example, 2^3 is producing 16 instead of 8 as expected.

Comment: My mistake, I updated it

Comment: No worries. I'm just jealous because you jumped on the answer so fast. :)